# How to run a script after OpenVPN initialization is completed?

Tags: networking, openvpn

**Background**: I want to check the speed of the various servers of my VPN provider and wrote a script which runs `iperf3` for each of the servers. The script does not modify the networking setup in any way.

**The problem**: while a plain `openvpn` command brings in a functional tunnel, adding the script breaks the communication.

*Please also see my **EDIT** at the end of the question which may an indication of what is going on. I also modified the title of the question for that reason*

### Case 0: no `openvpn` - networking OK

The routing table is

```
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.46
```

### Case 1: plain `openvpn` - networking OK

The command

```
# openvpn --config at3.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn --auth-user-pass auth.txt

(...)
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.7.7.210 peer 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip route add 37.252.190.165/32 via 10.0.3.1
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.7.7.1/32 via 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:06:17 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

brings in a tunnel with the associated routes

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.46
10.7.7.1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
10.7.7.209 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.7.210
37.252.190.165 via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
```

Traceroute to `www.google.com` is OK

```
# traceroute 66.102.1.103
traceroute to 66.102.1.103 (66.102.1.103), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.7.7.1 (10.7.7.1)  32.933 ms  65.328 ms  65.332 ms
 2  37-252-190-129.rev.ipax.at (37.252.190.129)  65.341 ms  65.337 ms  65.335 ms
(...)
```

### Case 2: `openvpn` with a script - networking fails

OpenVPN started with

```
# openvpn --config at3.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn --auth-user-pass auth.txt --script-security 2 --route-delay 5 --route-up "./testlink.sh at3.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn"

(...)
Sat Mar  5 19:11:20 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sat Mar  5 19:11:20 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.7.7.210 peer 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:11:25 2016 /sbin/ip route add 37.252.190.165/32 via 10.0.3.1
Sat Mar  5 19:11:25 2016 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:11:25 2016 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209
Sat Mar  5 19:11:25 2016 /sbin/ip route add 10.7.7.1/32 via 10.7.7.209
+ server=at3.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn
+ iperf3 -J -c ping.online.net
```

The last two lines are the beginning of my script. `iperf3` hangs as it cannot reach the `iperf3` server.

The routing table looks good (= it is the same as the previous one with plain `openvpn`, I even did a `diff` on the outputs to be sure):

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
default via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0
10.0.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.46
10.7.7.1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
10.7.7.209 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.7.210
37.252.190.165 via 10.0.3.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.7.209 dev tun0
```

But the same traceroute to `www.google.com` fails:

```
# traceroute 66.102.1.103
traceroute to 66.102.1.103 (66.102.1.103), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 (...)
```

**Why?**

## EDIT

I did one more test: to have a simple, non-blocking script which echoes "hello" and exits.

To my surprise, the `traceroute` now works, after the `Initialization Sequence Completed` line was logged.

It looks like there are further initialization steps being done between the script launch and this log entry. **How in that case can I run a blocking script?** (blocking in the sense that it does some actions dependent on the network being up), or in other words - after the initialization is complete?

Comment: What init system?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu 15.10, so this is probably upstart?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `--route-up` as this is for adding routes as the tunnel comes up.

You could try using `--up`, which is intended for scripts that are to be run after the tunnel is fully established. If this still hangs you're going you need to kick off a subprocess `&`-style

Comment: I tried with `--up` but in that case the script is started before the routing is in place (so it uses the existing, pre-openvpn, routing table). Also, the routes are in place when starting with `--route-up`.

Comment: @WoJ you might fortuitously find the routes are in place with `--route-up` but this flag is intended for bringing up routes programmatically